# Magento 2 : Add custom filter to options class select ui component

Tags: magento2, uicomponents

In Magento 2.4 I have a table with following fields: ID, Label, CategoryId, StoreId.

I want to put this info in a AdminUi grid on which I'm using inline edit.
I'm allowing webmaster to only change CategoryId from the grid. CategoryId column is a select component and I have a class to bring options for that select CategoryOptions.php!

My problem is that I see all categories (I have 2 different websites on Magento instance with 2 different set of categories) in that dropdown generated by the CategoryOptions.php class when trying to edit a line (using inline edit).

I need to filter the category options for each grid line by the StoreId param which is known for each line.

Anybody could please help me with this issue?!